# ASP.NET Listbox not selecting multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, selection, multipleselection

I have a listbox in my webform from which I am trying to select multiple values, but I am only getting last selected values. I have tried in two ways. First I explicitly added list items:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>teama</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>teamb</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:ListBox>
```

Second, I tried to bind to a table in a database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListBox2.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
        string scon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test_AthiraConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(scon);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select department from department", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ListBox2.DataSource = ds;
        ListBox2.DataValueField = "department";
        ListBox2.DataTextField = "department";
        ListBox2.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Then I tried these different methods to select multiple items on `buttonclick event`

First:

```
string k =null ,k1 = null;
foreach (int i in ListBox2.GetSelectedIndices())
{
    k1 = ListBox2.Items[i].Text + "/";
    k += k1;
    Response.Write(k);
}
```

Second:

```
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox2.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        k += li.Text + "/";
        Response.Write(k);
    }
}
```

Third:

```
k = String.Join("/", ListBox2.Items
                             .Cast<ListItem>()
                             .Where(i => i.Selected)
                             .Select(i=>i.Value)
                             .ToArray());
Response.Write(k);
```

Fourth:

```
for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (ListBox2.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        k1 = ListBox2.Items[i].Text + "/";
        k += k1;
        Response.Write(k);
    }
}
```

But none of them seem to work. I am getting only the last selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access the items in the list as follow and check their properties.

```
    IEnumerator ie =  ListBox2.Items.GetEnumerator();

    while (ie.MoveNext())
    {
        ListItem li = (ListItem)ie.Current;
        //Use ListItem here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code, It will return coma separator string for Listbox selected value

```
  public string GetSelectedValues()
    {
        string selectedVal = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (int index in lstbox.GetSelectedIndices())
        {
            if (i == 0) 
               selectedVal = lstbox.Items[index].Value;
            else
              selectedVal = selectedVal + ";" + lstbox.Items[index].Value.ToString();
            i++;
        }
        return selectedVal ;

    }
```